# How to move the "hot corner" of the messaging tray in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, messaging-tray

I have two monitors, side by side, and my main monitor is on the left.

In Gnome Shell, the task-bar can be quickly looked at by moving the mouse to the bottom right hot corner, but since I have a monitor to the right, it is really hard to not simply fly over to the next monitor when trying to access it.

Can I move that hot corner so that it is on the left bottom corner?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this GNOME extension to change the messaging tray hot corner. But, it also moves the icons to the left side.

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/157/left-message-tray/

If you only want to change the hot corner and not the icons, you can use this extension:

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/309/hot-corn-dog/

By default, it only changes the hot corner of the overview. You can customize it to only change the hot corner of the messaging tray by following the instructions provided here:

- https://euhiemf.github.io/Hot-Corn-Dog/#customization

---

To summarize the instructions, open the js file

```
gedit ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/Hot-Corn-Dog.senatorn@github.com/extension.js
```

Edit the following line:

```
const SYSTEM_TRAY_HOT_CORNER = right;
```

to

```
const SYSTEM_TRAY_HOT_CORNER = left;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's another way to do this, but you can find an extension that allows this here: [Left/Middle Message Tray](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/157/left-message-tray/)

You may need to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter the command 'r' (without quotes) to enable the extension.